What are the most widely used responses to Christian claims of supersessionism?
Christians claim that the Jewish nation is no longer chosen by God, and has been replaced or superseded by Christianity (Supersessionism). I would like to know what the most popular or frequently cited responses Judaism offers to this claim (if/when Jews choose to engage the claim at all).

Dunno how often it's cited to such effect but I think  לא איש אל ויכזב, ובן-אדם ויתנחם; ההוא אמר ולא יעשה, ודבר ולא יקימנה packs a nice punch

Is there a need to respond to lies? Doesn't giving a response make it seem like their is an opinion worth respecting?

As the argument is predicated on the text of the Gospels, the simplest response is "there is no accepted source for the idea."

@Dude historically we have been forced to answer, there were some famous disputations that summoned rabbinic leadership to answer Christian claims (scroll down to medieval disputations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputation). And of course, we ought know how to answer those that missionize to us in order to protect our brethren from falling into their snares.

https://aish.com/78624517/

The founding of Israel in 1948

My Rosh Yeshiva ran an anti-missionary course, and I attended and what stands out from my memory is the two dozen or so times that the Torah says it is eternal and will never be changed.

@RabbiKaii I also have a lot of sources that would be a good response to this question. I kind of wish we could open it so we could actually answer this question

There are many sources in Tanach that contradict the doctrine of supersessionism, including Y'sha'yahu 54:10 (and that whole chapter). See also here and the discussions here.

Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101602/did-rabbi-joseph-albo-say-the-mitzvoth-will-be-abolished/104442#104442

1 In my understanding, Judaism and Christianity utilize the same hermeneutic principles, so interpreting Biblical texts would be completely useless.  2 Christianity is a very wide umbrella term for numerous dogmas and views from the 1st century Jamesian church to Mormonism. 3 Rambam's 13 principles were proposed (pretty unintentionally) in the 13th century so for the previous 12 centuries it was undecided what fundamental Jewish dogmas are.

4 on the other hand, the four Canonical Gospels address the Jews exclusively so the concept of supersessionism was clearly a later Paulean apologetics rather than a fundamental belief.

I don't think most Christians would say the Jewish nation has been superseded/disbanded.  Many Christians tend to get this confused as well.  They would say that Second Temple Judaism was superseded (also it no longer exists) and that Rabbinic Judaism is a different religion that has developed over the past 2000 years.  The Jewish people are still considered to be a divine institution, but they are currently in a state of apostasy.  If you want to see for yourself read Romans 11 and Nostra ætate.
